# Use Folder From Desktop in Google Colab

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, google-colaboratory

I downloaded the Flicker8k_Dataset (a folder with lots of pictures). I am looking for a way to load that into Google Colab without using Google Drive (it would take 5 hours to upload to Google Drive). What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: so do you want to upload it again and again, as you will lose data when google colab times out roughly after 6 hours

Comment: is the filesize less than 100 mb

Comment: No, it is more than 100 mb

Comment: I agree with @Jodh Singh you can try wget see this link https://mc.ai/import-data-into-google-colaboratory/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wget command to download the dataset into your google drive and use it from there. The other way to use colab on your local dataset would be to run the colab on a local machine.